# Run IntelliJ JSP code in Chrome rather than display source code

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp, intellij-idea, server-configuration

When developing a web page, IntelliJ has browser icons which appear in the top right corner of the editor when you mouse over the area.  It used to be for me that if the active file in the editor was a JSP, I could click on my IntelliJ-Chrome icon.  This would launch Chrome and what would be displayed would be what the JSP would look like in a browser.  I imagine that it was a preview of sorts.  This way, I didn't need to run my entire program when all I wanted was to see what my JSP looked like.

I recently reinstalled all my software and lost all my previous settings.  Now, when I click on my IntelliJ-Chrome icon, Chrome just displays the JSP source code that is in the editor.  How do I get Chrome to run the JSP instead of just display the code?

Everything works fine when I run the entire project through Tomcat.

**Additional information 01:**

I noticed that when Chrome is displaying these JSP's, the address bar shows the location of the file on my hard drive rather than through localhost.  I do of course have a Tomcat Run Configuration set for the project, so I wonder if there is a setting in IntelliJ that is causing the JSP to not get sent through my Tomcat configuration.  I have looked this up in the IntelliJ forums and found [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207045695-changing-url-to-localhost) which addresses a similar issue.  The answer given is:

> You have to configure and mark as default a deployment entry at
>   "Settings | Deployment

**Additional Information 02:**

When using these icons, I believe what is launched is not necessarily any run configuration, but the path configuration of the browser.  This is located in IntelliJ at Settings -> Tools -> Web Browser.

[image]

I can modify the path to go to http:\localhost:8080\, but what this does is launch the OS default browser, not Chrome, at the project welcome page, not the active page in the editor.

Comment: JSP's are not run by a browser, such as Chrome. They run on the server (for example Tomcat) and, when they run, produce HTML that is sent to the browser. So there is no way to "get Chrome to run the JSP code".

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an active [Tomcat run/debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Rio.png). Once you start it and the app is deployed on the server, clicking the browser icon in the editor will open the URL corresponding to the the `.jsp` file in the browser.

IDE needs to know the [deployment context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChpJv.png) and [the server URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm4Y6.png) for this feature to work which is not possible without Tomcat run configuration.

Clicking the icon for `index.jsp` in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X10UA.png) will open `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` in the browser.

Comment: Even with Tomcat configured as you point out, it seems the JSP's launch from my hard drive rather than from localhost.  The address looks like this: `file:///F:/Programming/Education/Java/Murach%20Java%20Servlets%20JSP%203E/Chapter%2013%20JPA/Login%20Register%20View%2002/web/welcome.jsp`

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: JSP must be in the web resource directory that is a part of the artifact built by IntelliJ IDEA and deployed on Tomcat via this Run/Debug configuration, Deployment tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your Tomcat server is responsible for rendering of the JSP code. Browser just parces HTML (potentially with CSS/JS). JSP is serverside technology. You should run server first, than your favorite icon should work.